# Why does my mission marker disappear in Saints Row 3?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

When I'm doing a mission, for example, the mission "Live! With Killbane". I put the transmitters on the towers and followed the van and then I'm suppose to head to the interview. The mission marker shows up on some building that I fly to and then after I land on the building it disappears?

I can't go down the building and when I'm out of the helicopter too long it says that I need to get back in it. But when I do I see no marker of where I should go. It's so confusing and quite annoying because I have failed 3-5 missions because of this glitch/bug. Anyone else have this problem and or know what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Markers in Saints Row 3 disappear in general when you stand on them, or are close enough. Not much to do to fix it, it's just that you should look around for the actual objective.

They do disappear before the actual objective for assassination and vehicle theft missions, but that's a particular case. That's because in such case you have to do something to bring the target out, or just look around.

From what I remember, for your specific mission, when you are at this stage, you have to enter the building from a door on the roof. If it's not there, there is a problem, indeed. But it should.

Comment: yea, you are supposed to go in the building, I don't know why its telling him to get back into the helicopter....

Comment: @yx. - indeed, I recall something like this. Probably there is something wrong in the script, so it keeps looping on "get in the helicopter - go there"